# EventStore.ClientAPI.Exceptions.RetriesLimitReachedException

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, eventstoredb

I've created and Web ApI based on Docker and EventStore. I used to send a request on swagger without 500 error status code but now when I want to send a new one, it returns 500 status code with the following:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ck4r.png)

How can I change the limit of EventStore retry limit?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using the legacy protocol and client? It won't be supported anymore.

Comment: What do you mean with legacy protocol and client?

Comment: The package you use is the legacy package, using the legacy protocol which is no longer supported